# Signal processing-remove noise for a series of spectra

Tags: python, r, signal-processing, linear-algebra, noise

I am a chemist and measured a series of spectra of one compound under increasing temperature. (-200 degree to 0 degree). The shape of spectra is very similar at different temperature. The only difference is the intensity: at higher temperature the intensity is lower. 
My problem is at high temperature, e.g. 0 degree, the real signal's intensity is quite close to the background noise's amplitude, which make the spectra at high temperature very noisy. I tried some simple smoothing method but the result is not good.
The noise is much less affected by the temperature change than the real signal(which means we can assume the background noise doesn't change too much). Thus, I wonder is there any method that can remove the noise(background) using the series of spectra I have, since they share the "common" background noise.

Any information (e.g. name of method, tools in python or R, reference) will be helpful. Thanks for your help!

Comment: could you provide some sample data?

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: Probably he/she isn't looking anymore for a solution. But I'm facing a similar problem.